# knockout.js variable used as an ID

Tags: javascript, web, knockout.js, web-deployment

I am trying to iterate through a knockouts array and each element has to have a unique id. I have an id in my data structure which I wanna use. well probably it is easier if I show it.

```
    <div class="row">      
         <div data-bind="foreach: something">
             <div style="display: none;" class="col-xs-12" data-bind="attr: {id: id}">
                      hidden stuff
             </div>
             <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-menu-trigger-button">
                 <div style=" height:inherit; line-height:6px; cursor:pointer; color:black" onclick="$('#' + $id).slideToggle('slow1', null);"> //problem is I assume here
             </div>      

         </div>

    </div>
```

So I believe when I bind the id as an attribute is good but when I try to define the onclick event then I dont know how to get the value of id.

Comment: There can be a number of problems (including the fact that `id` attribute cannot start with a digit), but more importantly: what you're trying to do is also possible by using the [`click`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) binding or a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) (it has an example for `slideVislbe` in there). Please review these alternatives and/or consider updating your question so it allows us to *easily* repro the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `click` binding and `id` like for `attr`:

```
data-bind="click: function() { $('#' + id()).slideToggle('slow1', null); }"
```

Here it is unwrapped (`()`) because it's concatenated with `'#'`.

Comment: @DarlekSupreme Congrats on choosing the inferior solution.

Comment: Why the downvote, wrong answer? Does not answer the question?

Comment: I don't know where the downvote comes from - it isn't mine, anyway. My guess is, it's because it goes against the principles of knockout to solve it that way, i.e., it's not a clean solution, but a makeshift.

Comment: Ok, but @DarlekSupreme was trying to understand how to reference the `id` knockout property in his click function. This answer explains that. For a deeper knockout lesson, there is knockout documentation.

Comment: "I want to hammer a nail into this wall with a bottle. But it does not seem to work..." - "Here, let me show you how to hold the bottle right..."  -- Notice anything wrong with this kind of answer?

Comment: Don't get me wrong. Your answer *works* and it kinda solves the immediate problem of the OP, but it's not a particularly good way to solve this problem. Especially High rep users on SO ought to give good advice, not just do what the OP asks for. (my personal opinion)

Answer (score 5):

First, most important thing: **Never use inline event handlers.** Period. Remove all the `onclick="..."` and whatever other event attributes you might have from your HTML.

Especially with knockout, which handles all the context for you and offers a `click` binding you're shooting yourself in the foot with inline event handlers.

With knockout it's important to have a working, abstract *view model* before you turn it into a *view* (i.e., a visual HMTL representation).

---

In your case you want to encapsulate the *visibility* of an item. That means you need an observable, lets call it `visible`, and a function to toggle that property, `toggleVisible()`. Simple enough:

```
function Something(id) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.visible = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleVisible = function () {
        self.visible( !self.visible() );
    };
}
```

---

The next thing you want is to encapsulate the animation when an item's `visible` propery changes. That means you must subscribe to the `visible` property in some way and make jQuery do it's thing.

Best suited for this task is a [custom binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that animates the element. That's not too hard, either. Let's call it `slideToggle`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideToggle = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var shouldBeVisible = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        // initially, display or hide the element instantly
        $(element)[shouldBeVisible ? "show" : "hide"]();
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var shouldBeVisible = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        // during interactive operation, use transition effect
        $(element)[shouldBeVisible ? "slideDown" : "slideUp"]("fast");
    }
};
```

I recommend you read about custom binding handlers, they are incredibly useful.

---

Now we have abstracted all the moving parts into their separate containers. Let's use them with this main ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.something = ko.observableArray([
        new Something("id1"),
        new Something("id2")
    ]);
}
```

and this view:

```html
<div class="row">
     <div data-bind="foreach: something">
         <div class="col-xs-12" data-bind="slideToggle: visible">
            hidden stuff
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-1 hidden-menu-trigger-button">
             <div data-bind="click: toggleVisible">Click Me!</div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Notice how everything falls into place and you don't even need a reference to an element ID because knockout handles the context for you. Also the `slideToggle` animation becomes trivially easy to re-use and your view becomes less of a pain to look at.

- See it live over here: http://jsfiddle.net/nkr9o3un/
- And how easy it is to extend once things have been abstracted in this manner: http://jsfiddle.net/nkr9o3un/2/. Try to do this with a bunch of inline functions.

Comment: Now that's how you write an answer!